# Fragmentをreplaceしても一つ前のFragmentが残る

Tags: android, fragment

現在`Fragment`を使って画面を切り替えようとしているのですが、`transaction.replace`を行うと、layout_Aの画面とlayout_Bの画面が重なった状態で表示されてしまいます。試しに`transaction.remove`をして`transaction.add`を行っても結果は同じでした。`Fragment`の使い方が間違っているのでしょうか？どこを修正すれば画面を切り替えれるようになるでしょうか？すみませんが、宜しくお願いします。

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_changeMode, new FragmentB());
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

layout_A.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment_change"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="taro.ghost.fragment.FragmentA"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

layout_B.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/contact" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

レイアウトXMLで指定した`Fragment`は`add`や`replace`対象にしてはいけません。

この場合、`layout_A.xml`を次のように変更し、`onCreate()`あたりで`FragmentA`をaddするようにします。

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。レイアウトXMLで指定したFragmentはaddやreplaceしてはいけないのですね。知りませんでした。帰宅後一度自分のコードを修正したいと思います。